# How to prevent Eclipse use existing file tab when opening a new file

Tags: java, eclipse

This sometimes happens:  when I try to open a file using mouse click, the java file is opened in the previous existed file tab, so the previously opened file tab is replaced by this new file.  This is annoying since I wanted to compare the two file and Eclipse only open one for me. I only have about 4-5 tabs so it is not that I have too many files opened.

Most of the time, a new file tab will be added.  How to change the behavior of Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the file is only opened in the previous tab if you open it from the search panel. If you want to compare two files, open them from the Package Explorer or Navigator panels.

However, you can change the behavior in the way described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/130353/how-to-leave-the-open-file-in-eclipse-tab-after-search